# COPY query with variable path

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a stored procedure that imports a file but what I've noticed is that COPY can be followed by string literal and no variable?

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
FUNCTION insert_file (IN filepath VARCHAR(255)) ... 
   COPY filepath ...
```

is it even possible or I need to do some magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
FUNCTION insert_file (IN filepath VARCHAR(255)) ... 
sqltxt:='COPY table_name from '''||filepath||''' with (FORMAT csv)';
execute sqltxt;
```

'''||variable||''' will produce 'value' with quotation marks.

'||variable||' will produce the value without quotation marks. usefully for table names and integers for example.

You need to declare sqltxt as text.

Comment: Use quote_literal() or format() instead of direct concatenation. Otherwise it fails and is SQL-injectable if the parameter contains a quote.